# Google Map V2 crash when used in ViewPager fragment?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a problem where I'm trying to use Google Maps v2 in my Android app.

My plan is to have a viewpager with two pages (a "detail" page and a "googlemap" page)

I've set the whole thing up, and it's giving me some weird results:

When I start swiping to the "googlemap" page, in the middle of the animation (like if I hold the viewpager halfway), I can see the map load up properly.It's just there.

All the things I've set up (markers, camera, animation...) run as they are supposed to.

But as soon **I complete the swipe, and the googlemap page takes over the entire screen, the whole thing crashes.**

Any idea what could cause it?

Here is all the relevant code:

**FragmentMap.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MapFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private static View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view != null) 
        {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(view);
        }
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        return view;

    }

    public static MapFragment newInstance() {
        MapFragment f = new MapFragment();
        return f;
    }
}
```

**DetailActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    int extraID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_holder);

        Intent prevIntent = getIntent();
        extraID = prevIntent.getIntExtra("selected_ID", 0);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                return DetailFragment.newInstance(extraID);
            case 1:
                return MapFragment.newInstance();
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

**detailHolder.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

EDIT:
**logcat**

```
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:394)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:389)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:99)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1048)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5230)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
09-28 13:41:42.830: E/AndroidRuntime(12693):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please, post the logcat output of the error.

Comment: Thanks, forgot about it. Added.

Comment: Please post the complete logcat, at least until you read "caused by... ". Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my opinions:

1. Change detailHolder.xml to detailholder.xml android xml files are all lower case
2. This code might be causing map problems

   ```
   if (parent != null)
   parent.removeView(view);
   ```

You are using relative layout, and you remove any of the views associated with the layout it will affect all the layout in the fields. You can use other layout like linearlayout.

Your code is not complete. How have you used DetailFragment.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) instead of [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html), for some cases it might help.